# Listview with pull to refresh Scroll down to last item when adding header-view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget

I have created one pull to refresh listview now when I scroll or pull little bit then I have to add header view.

here my custom listview class

```
package com.app.refreshableList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.xxxxxx.R;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.el;

public class RefreshableListView extends ListView {

    Boolean isScrool = false;
    private View mHeaderContainer = null;
    private View mHeaderView = null;
    private ImageView mArrow = null;
    private ProgressBar mProgress = null;
    private TextView mText = null;
    private float mY = 0;
    private float mHistoricalY = 0;
    private int mHistoricalTop = 0;
    private int mInitialHeight = 0;
    private boolean mFlag = false;
    private boolean mArrowUp = false;
    private boolean mIsRefreshing = false;
    private int mHeaderHeight = 0;
    private OnRefreshListener mListener = null;

    private static final int REFRESH = 0;
    private static final int NORMAL = 1;
    private static final int HEADER_HEIGHT_DP = 62;
    private static final String TAG = RefreshableListView.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListViewObserver mObserver;
    private View mTrackedChild;
    private int mTrackedChildPrevPosition;
    private int mTrackedChildPrevTop;
    OnTouchListener touch;

    View vHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mTrackedChild == null) {
            if (getChildCount() > 0) {
                mTrackedChild = getChildInTheMiddle();
                mTrackedChildPrevTop = mTrackedChild.getTop();
                mTrackedChildPrevPosition = getPositionForView(mTrackedChild);
            }
        } else {
            boolean childIsSafeToTrack = mTrackedChild.getParent() == this
                    && getPositionForView(mTrackedChild) == mTrackedChildPrevPosition;
            if (childIsSafeToTrack) {
                int top = mTrackedChild.getTop();
                if (mObserver != null) {
                    float deltaY = top - mTrackedChildPrevTop;
                    mObserver.onScroll(deltaY);
                }
                mTrackedChildPrevTop = top;
            } else {
                mTrackedChild = null;
            }
        }

    }

    private View getChildInTheMiddle() {
        return getChildAt(getChildCount() / 2);
    }

    public void setObserver(ListViewObserver observer) {
        mObserver = observer;
    }

    public RefreshableListView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public RefreshableListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public RefreshableListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize();
    }

    public void setOnRefreshListener(final OnRefreshListener l) {
        mListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setOnTouchListener(l);
    }

    public void completeRefreshing() {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(NORMAL, mHeaderHeight, 0));
        mIsRefreshing = false;
        invalidateViews();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mHandler.removeMessages(REFRESH);
            mHandler.removeMessages(NORMAL);
            mY = mHistoricalY = ev.getY();
            if (mHeaderContainer.getLayoutParams() != null) {
                mInitialHeight = mHeaderContainer.getLayoutParams().height;
            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mHistoricalTop = getChildAt(0).getTop();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!mIsRefreshing) {
                if (mArrowUp) {
                    startRefreshing();
                    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(REFRESH,
                            (int) (ev.getY() - mY) / 2 + mInitialHeight, 0));
                } else {
                    if (getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0) {
                        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(NORMAL,
                                (int) (ev.getY() - mY) / 2 + mInitialHeight, 0));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(REFRESH,
                        (int) (ev.getY() - mY) / 2 + mInitialHeight, 0));
            }
            mFlag = false;
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                 && getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
            float direction = ev.getY() - mHistoricalY;
            int height = (int) (ev.getY() - mY) / 2 + mInitialHeight;
            if (height < 0) {
                height = 0;
            }

            float deltaY = Math.abs(mY - ev.getY());
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
            if (deltaY > config.getScaledTouchSlop()) {

                // Scrolling downward
                if (direction > 0) {
                    // Refresh bar is extended if top pixel of the first item is
                    // visible
                    if (getChildAt(0) != null) {
                        if (getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0) {
                            if (mHistoricalTop < 0) {

                                // mY = ev.getY(); // TODO works without
                                // this?mHistoricalTop = 0;
                            }
                            // if (isScrool == true) {
                            //
                            // } else {
                            // isScrool = true;
                            // addHeaderView(vHeader);
                            //
                            // // Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            // // getContext(), R.anim.bounce_animation);
                            // // startAnimation(anim);
                            //
                            // smoothScrollToPosition(getChildAt(0).getTop());
                            // // bottom_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // }
                            // Extends refresh bar

                            /*****
                             * commented by me on 10-09-2014
                             */
                            setHeaderHeight(height);

                            // Stop list scroll to prevent the list from
                            // overscrolling
                            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                            mFlag = false;
                        }
                    }

                } else if (direction < 0) {
                    // Scrolling upward

                    // Refresh bar is shortened if top pixel of the first item
                    // is
                    // visible
                    if (getChildAt(0) != null) {
                        if (getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0) {
                            setHeaderHeight(height);

                            // If scroll reaches top of the list, list scroll is
                            // enabled
                            if (getChildAt(1) != null
                                    && getChildAt(1).getTop() <= 1 && !mFlag) {
                                ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                                mFlag = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            mHistoricalY = ev.getY();
        }
        try {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performItemClick(final View view, final int position,
            final long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            // This is the refresh header element
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.performItemClick(view, position - 1, id);
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vHeader = inflator.inflate(R.layout.search_header, null);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mHeaderContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.refreshable_list_header,
                null);
        mHeaderView = mHeaderContainer
                .findViewById(R.id.refreshable_list_header);
        mArrow = (ImageView) mHeaderContainer
                .findViewById(R.id.refreshable_list_arrow);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) mHeaderContainer
                .findViewById(R.id.refreshable_list_progress);
        mText = (TextView) mHeaderContainer
                .findViewById(R.id.refreshable_list_text);
        addHeaderView(mHeaderContainer);

        mHeaderHeight = (int) (HEADER_HEIGHT_DP * getContext().getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density);

        setHeaderHeight(0);
    }

    private void setHeaderHeight(final int height) {
        if (height <= 1) {
            mHeaderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mHeaderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Extends refresh bar
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) mHeaderContainer.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp == null) {
            lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
        lp.height = height;
        mHeaderContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Refresh bar shows up from bottom to top
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams headerLp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mHeaderView
                .getLayoutParams();
        if (headerLp == null) {
            headerLp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

        headerLp.topMargin = -mHeaderHeight + height;

        mHeaderView.setLayoutParams(headerLp);

        if (!mIsRefreshing) {
            // If scroll reaches the trigger line, start refreshing
            if (height > mHeaderHeight && !mArrowUp) {
                mArrow.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getContext(), R.anim.rotate));
                mText.setText("Release to update");
                rotateArrow();
                mArrowUp = true;
            } else if (height < mHeaderHeight && mArrowUp) {
                mArrow.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getContext(), R.anim.rotate));
                mText.setText("Pull down to update");
                rotateArrow();
                mArrowUp = false;
            }else {
                if (isScrool == true) {

                } else {
                     isScrool = true;
                    addHeaderView(vHeader);

                    // Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    // getContext(), R.anim.bounce_animation);
                    // startAnimation(anim);

                    smoothScrollToPosition(getChildAt(0).getTop());
                    // bottom_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void rotateArrow() {
        Drawable drawable = mArrow.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(180.0f, canvas.getWidth() / 2.0f,
                canvas.getHeight() / 2.0f);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        mArrow.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private void startRefreshing() {
        mArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mText.setText("Loading...");
        mIsRefreshing = true;

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onRefresh(this);
        }
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            int limit = 0;
            switch (msg.what) {
            case REFRESH:
                limit = mHeaderHeight;
                break;
            case NORMAL:
                limit = 0;
                break;
           }

            // Elastic scrolling
            if (msg.arg1 >= limit) {
                setHeaderHeight(msg.arg1);
                int displacement = (msg.arg1 - limit) / 10;
                if (displacement == 0) {
                    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(msg.what,
                            msg.arg1 - 1, 0));
                } else {
                    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(msg.what,
                            msg.arg1 - displacement, 0));
                }
            }
        }

    };

    public interface OnRefreshListener {
        public void onRefresh(RefreshableListView listView);
    }

    public static interface ListViewObserver {
        public void onScroll(float deltaY);
    }
}
```

here in method `dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev)` i have make one condition

```
if (isScrool == true) {

} else {
    isScrool = true;
    addHeaderView(vHeader);

    // Animation anim =
    // AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
    // getContext(), R.anim.bounce_animation);
    // startAnimation(anim);

    smoothScrollToPosition(getChildAt(0).getTop());
    // bottom_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

here `addHeaderView(vHeader);`
 **adds header but my listview scroll down to last item** can anyone could tell me what's happening here?

Comment: scrollTo(0,getChildAt(0).getTop() - vHeader.getHeight()); doens't work? Or smoothScrollToPosition(0);

Comment: well its not working can you tell me this the right place to add headerview ? @PedroOliveira

Comment: Like @T-rush pointed out. Can't you just put setSelectionAfterHeaderView(); instead of smoothScroll ?

Comment: i tried that also but cant get

Answer (score 0):

Try to call **`listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();`**. This will scroll `ListView` to top.

Comment: well i need to call in public class RefreshableListView extends ListView class

Comment: Just add `setSelectionAfterHeaderView();` instead of `smoothScrollToPosition(getChildAt(0).getTop());`. May be it work.

Comment: Okay...put `setSelection(0);` and check again.

Comment: not working. can you check my dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) method

Comment: I've check your method and it seems like the problem is somewhere else. I think `ListView` scrolls down because of refreshing. So put `setSelectionAfterHeaderView();` or `setSelection(0);` at the end of `startRefreshing()` method. I don't know it works or not, but try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61035/discussion-between-ando-masahashi-and-t-rush).